# laravel model relations for forum

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm currenty making a forum in Laravel, just for the sake of learning, but I can't get my relations working well.

I have a Thread, Post and User model.

I've tried the following:

```
class User {
    public function thread() {
        return $this->hasMany('Thread');
    }

    public function post() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Thread', 'Post');
    }
}


class Thread {

    public function post() {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}

class Post {

     public function thread() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Thread');
     }

     public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
     }
}
```

With this method I can get a specific thread, and the posts that belong in it. But I can't grab the user who has posted the post in the thread.

I hope my problem is clear enough for you. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity I suggest you name your relations singular for hasOne/belongsTo and plural for belongsToMany/hasMany

so on the User and Thread it will be:

```
public function posts() ...
```

Now, this is in wrong order:

```
class User {
  public function posts() {
    // return $this->hasManyThrough('Thread', 'Post'); // wrong, change to:
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'Thread');
  }
}
```

Apart from that your relations look good, so you should be able to do this:

```
$thread = Thread::with('posts.user')->find($threadId); // eager load relations
$thread->posts; // Eloquent Collection of Post models
foreach ($thread->posts as $post)
{
  $post->user; // author's User model
}
```

And by the way you can always have a look at the Laravel.io source: https://github.com/LaravelIO/laravel.io/

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! It works a bit better now. There is only one thing I have forgotten to specify. I have a `threads` `users` and `posts` table. In the `posts` table, I only put the user_id there, and I want to get the username from the `users` table that corresponds to that user_id.

Comment: Exactly, then in that loop I wrote you can access username like this $post->user->username;

Comment: When I try that, I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" error. When I access it like $post->user()->username, I get "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$username".

Comment: Never mind, I have found my error. I did not specify my local key to look in in my Post model. `public function userr() {
  return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user');
 }` The user_id column was named 'user'. That was the problem

Comment: So you don't have related user in db or there is no user_id value at all for that post and $post->user returns null. Also is users PK called 'id' ?

Comment: The foreign key was named 'user', so I had to specify that. Now it works. But I have renamed my columns to user_id from now on.